# text filter in postgresql (how to find rows without data in a field)

Tags: postgresql

I have the following case:

```
Select count(*) from cliente
```

gives 1964

```
Select count(*) from cliente where concli between 'A' and 'ZZ'
```

gives 1939

```
Select count(*) from cliente where concli not between 'A' and 'ZZ'
```

gives 0

How do I get the other 25 rows?

Comment: `Select count(*) from cliente where concli IS NULL;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `not between 'A' and 'ZZ'` is tested on rows where `concli` has a value, that is, `concli` is not `null`. The 25 rows missing are certainly `null` values. So your second query should be :

```
Select count(*) from cliente where concli not between 'A' and 'ZZ' or concli is null;
```